# how to access the API's through IP address

Tags: angular

I am trying to call the backend APIs which is running in azure VM, I am getting the response from the API when I call the APIs with DNS name, but when I call the same API with the private IP address I am getting the error like this.

[image]

**My Current Code **

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
      import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'


      @Component({
         selector: 'apicall',
         templateUrl: './apicall.component.html',
         styleUrls: ['./apicall.component.css']
     })
    export class ApicallComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   url = 'http://dev.india.cloudapp.azure.com/app/dim/analyticsdim/get'


   ngOnInit() {
     this.getdata()
   }

  getdata(){
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response=>{
     console.log(response)
   })
  }
 }
```

If I change the URL like this:

```
  url = 'http://10.0.*.*1:4532/appdim/analyticsdim/get'
```

I am getting the error that I have shown in the Image.

Please help me In this I am facing this problem from last 2 months.

Comment: Is the port **4532** you are using **Open** that controls both inbound and outbound traffic? if not follow this link - http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: @ShubhamBhokare    I have opened the port 4532 in the backend server, but still, I am facing the same problem..